# wxPython: Event Handling Order for Multiple Handlers of the Same Event at the Same Event Propagation Level

Tags: wxpython

I am a relatively experienced user with wxPython but have always had trouble with how wxPython deals with binding multiple event handlers to the same event (I know that that I am being general, hopefully my example below is more specific). This is not a question about "event propagation" as it usually referred to in the wxPython community.

Here is the sample code (If it didn't come out right: I had trouble figuring out the code block system for the forum):

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
       wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title,
                      wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(200, 100))

       Panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
       TopSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
       Panel.SetSizer(TopSizer)

       Text = wx.TextCtrl(Panel, -1, "Type text here")
       TopSizer.Add(Text, 1, wx.EXPAND)

       Text.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN,self.OnKeyText)
       Text.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyText2)


    def OnKeyText(self, event):
        print "OnKeyText"
        event.Skip()

    def OnKeyText2(self, event):
        print "OnKeyText2"
        event.Skip()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        Frame = MainFrame(None, -1, "Event Order Demo")
        Frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(Frame)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = MyApp(0)
    App.MainLoop()
```

---

The function "OnKeyText2" gets executed first, so I figure the behavior for the "event stack" (Is there a proper terminology for this part of wxPython instead of "event stack"?) for this control is: Each new handler bound to the same event at the same level of propagation goes to the top of the stack (executed first) and not the bottom (executed second).

Even though I understand this, it has become a real pain in my application because I have subclasses of a class where the base class functions bind some events, then the subclasses bind their additional events afterwords.

I feel like the events get put into the "event stack" backwards (bind the event you want to have happen last first). Is there a way to have the events *append* to the "event stack" and not be inserted in the beginning?

If I am misunderstanding the event.Skip() command or am missing something, please let me know! :) Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do? I don't want to have the events strung together (For example: have OnKeyText(), once done, call OnKeyText2()) because in my app one of the event handlers is shared by all subclasses and the other is not.

If the answer is that "it just needs to be done in reverse order" then I will have to accept that and make the changes to my app.

If the answer is that I should use event propagation between the control and the panels to control the order of event handlers, I feel like I run into the same problem unless I keep the number of event handlers to one for each propagation level.

Thanks in advance!
Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand why the order is important in your case, but I had a similar issue.

I originally had one event handler on several `TextCtrl`, which actually did the work of reacting upon a `EVT_TEXT_ENTER`. I then wanted to validate the string entered, as I was expecting a positive integer in the text field. I subclassed `TextCtrl` for that purpose, and hooked an event handler in the subclass for the string validation.

Of course, there was a problem: it worked fine with only half of the `TextCtrl`s, when the validation by the subclass event handler was done before the work by the superclass event handler.

I did not investigate how the handlers were managed/processed internally, but fixed the design instead: the subclass event handler is bound to `EVT_TEXT_ENTER`, which fires, after the string is validated, a custom event I introduced. The superclass event handler is now hooked on this custom event rather than `EVT_TEXT_ENTER`.

This way, I'm always sure of the processing order, and it is insensitive to unbinding/rebinding. I could hook more handlers on the custom event if the string validation is a prerequisite for them.